# Copying tar.gz file as binary type over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh-tunneling

I am new to Mac or linux world. I am trying to ssh into one of the router and copy firware file from my pc. I can copy the `tar.gz` file as is but I have been asked to copy as binary then I can do burn to upgrade the firmware version. How do I set the type of transfer as binary? Any advice is appreciated.

This is what I am doing:

```
scp -r /Users/xxx/Downloads/filename.tar.gz  root@192.168.12.1:"/tmp"
```

Comment: `scp` and `sftp` are "always" binary, unlike `ftp`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `-r` flag to `scp` as there is no directory specified (it's simply ignored in your context).

All files are always copied in binary format, so there is nothing more you need to do.